# Add click event to elements of a chart in superset

Tags: apache-superset

First,I follow [official site](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#start-with-docker),use docker and ubuntu 18, install superset,do not know is it the newest version of superset.

then I upload a csv as a table called "sales",csv is:

```
shop,sales
ibm,200
microsoft,100
sony,50
```

column shop is string type,"sales" is bigint type.

Then I add a bar chart and a big number chart.
The metric of the big number chart is sum(sales).

I Add these two chart to dashboard,it looks like:
[image: sales dashboard]
What I need is when I click the bar "ibm",the big number chart(sum int) shows 200,when I click the bar microsoft,it shows 100.

I found a [web page](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/5941) ,they say add call addFitler() on slice,but I can not find where is the slice and do not know how to addFilter.

Actually,I have many charts on a dashboard,and it is best if I click one element on any chart,other charts can change corresponding

Comment: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/7936